# To verify if a number is fibonacci or not

Tags: c++, fibonacci

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int fib0 = 0;
    int fib1 = 1;

    long long t;
    cin >> t;
    vector<long long> vec;
    //int count=0;
    vec.push_back(fib0);
    //count++;
    vec.push_back(fib1);
    //count++;
    long long sizeval=0;
    for(long long i=0;i<t;i++)
    {


        long long n;
        cin >> n;
        sizeval= vec.size();
       // cout << sizeval <<endl;
       // cout << vec.at(sizeval-1)<<endl;

        if(vec.at(sizeval-1)<n)
        {
            while(vec.at(sizeval-1)<n)
            {
              //  long long temp1=vec.at(sizeval-1);   //fib_n2
                //long long temp2=vec.at(sizeval-2);  //fib_n1
                long long temp=vec.at(sizeval-1)+vec.at(sizeval-2);
                vec.push_back(temp);
              //  cout << temp << endl;
                sizeval= vec.size();
               // cout << sizeval << endl;
            }
            if(vec.at(sizeval-1)==n)
            {
                cout << "IsFibo"<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "IsNotFibo"<<endl;
            }

        }
        else if(vec.at(sizeval-1)==n || vec.at(0)==n)
        {
            cout << "IsFibo" <<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            int found=0;
            long long k=0;
            long long l=vec.size()-1;
            while(k!=l)
            {


            long long mid = (k+l)/2;

            if(n==vec.at(mid))
            {
                cout << "IsFibo" << endl;
                found=1;
                break;

            }
            else if(n>vec.at(mid))
            {
                k=mid;
                l--;

            }
            else
            {
                l=mid;
                k++;
            }
            if(vec.at(k)==n || vec.at(l)==n)
                {
                    cout << "IsFibo" << endl;
                    found=1;
                    break;
                }
        }
        if(found==0)
        {
            cout << "IsNotFibo" << endl;
        }
        }

    }
          return 0;
}
```

My code is supposed to print "IsFib" if the number is part of the Fibonacci sequence, and "IsNotFib" if not. The problem is that sometimes while executing it, I get this error:

```
'std::out_of_range' what(): vector::_M_range_check
```

Can someone please help me with this error? I'm a little new to this so please walk me through!

Comment: look at me i'm cheating http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-number-fibonacci-number/

Comment: Please give us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not your full code. Trim down as much as you can while still getting the error. In addition, you'll want to check your indenting. It's a bit off in some places.

Comment: have a fibonacci list and first use for statement to check if any of your numbers match the values in fibonacci.

Comment: sorry if it does not adhere to what is expected!I'm a still new at this so please bear with me!

Comment: @user3676846 It's fine that you're new -- that's why we're helping you know what to do.

Comment: @newbiedoodle I really dont know how to reduce the code to reproduce the problem I'm getting since I dont understand the error!

Answer (score 1):

I don't yet quite follow your code, however that error means that you are either accessing the vector beyond its end, or before its beginning.

Rather than saving the size of the vector in an integer, use a std::vector::iterator to keep track of where you are in the vector, then use vec.begin() for its beginning, and vec.end() for ONE PAST THE END of the vector:

```
std::vector::iterator mark( vec.begin() );

if ( mark >= vec.begin() && mark < vec.end() )
   // You're looking inside the vector
else
   // you're before the beginning or past the end.
```

I'll look over your code again in a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to keep in memory two numbers to calculate fibonacci. And if you get a higher value than the one you are looking for, that's not a fibonacci number:

```
long t;
std::cin >> t;
long cur = 1;
long prev = 0;

while (cur < t) {
    long next = cur + prev;
    prev = cur;
    cur = next;
}

if (cur == t || t == 0)
    std::cout << " is fib" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << " is NOT fib" << std::endl;
```

EDIT: now, supposing I understood correctly your comment, if you want to check just the first `steps` numbers of the fibonacci sequence that would be:

```
long t;
std::cin >> t;
long cur = 1;
long prev = 0;
int steps;
std::cin >> steps;

while (cur < t && steps-- > 0) {
    long next = cur + prev;
    prev = cur;
    cur = next;
}

if ((cur == t || t == 0) && steps >= 0)
    std::cout << " is fib" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << " is NOT fib" << std::endl;
```

Comment: I believe you made a type -- you wrote `cit` instead of `cin`. I could be wrong, though; I don't use C++ much.

Comment: Sorry but I forgot to mention that in a single input I will be given the number of test cases and for those many numbers I have to identify fibonacci or not.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
while(k!=l)
```

to

```
while(k<l)
```

to always terminate the loop when number is not found in the vector.